# How to display a cube on rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using a PCD Visualizer, but, I changed to rviz, I was using the following command:

```
viewer.addCube(min_pt.x, max_pt.x, min_pt.y, max_pt.y, min_pt.z, max_pt.z, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, "Door1");
```

To add a cube to the visualization, but, I don't know how to perform this on rviz, since the fact that I don't use PCD Visualizer anymore, could you guys give some help to me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234238/how-to-display-a-cube-on-rviz?/) by [Nxzx](https://answers.ros.org/users/25604/nxzx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publish a marker of type cube to some topic and visualize it in Rviz.
here is an [introduction](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker).

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2